# Disabling login and register tab of converse.js, and connecting converse.js with openfire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openfire, converse.js

I am a beginner and using the plugin for the first time. I am working on the converse.js plugin for my website's chat application. Since I have a login for the users, I don't want them to relogin on the converse.js chat. Can someone please guide me as to what exactly needs to be done? I tried hiding the divs but only a part of it gets hidden (for the code i have provided only login and register tabs gets hidden). I need access the inner elements of the plugin so that whenever the page is loaded it makes a connection directly. I am using openfire.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Converse.js</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/converse.min.css">
  <script src="js/converse.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function showhide() {
      var div = document.getElementById("controlbox-tabs");
      if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Delete uls</button>

</body>

<script>
  require(['converse'], function(converse) {
    converse.initialize({
      auto_list_rooms: false,
      auto_subscribe: false,
      prebind: false,
      keepalive: true,
      bosh_service_url: 'https://conversejs.org/http-bind/', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
      hide_muc_server: false,
      i18n: locales.en, // Refer to ./locale/locales.js to see which locales are supported
      prebind: false,
      show_controlbox_by_default: true,
      roster_groups: true,
      allow_contact_requests: false
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var list = document.getElementById("controlbox-tabs");
    list.removeChild(list.childNodes[1]);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the divs selectively is not the correct way to approach the problem.
The **real** solution to login the user into website AND chat is to

> set up a BOSH session on your server, which converse.js can then connect to once the page loads.

Please refer to the Converse.js documentation for single session support: 
https://conversejs.org/docs/html/setup.html#session-support